# Trying to create sliders to control the hue, saturation, brightness, and size of shapes in my drawing application

Tags: processing

I'm trying to figure out how to use sliders to control the color for my drawing application, my code is as follows

```java
//Paint

//Buttons
boolean pointButton=false;
boolean lineButton=false;
boolean circleButton=false;
boolean rectButton=false;
boolean eraserButton=false;

//Colors
color current=color(#FFFFFF);//white

//Img
PImage img;

void setup()
{
  size(900, 600);
  background (255);

  //define palette
  stroke(220);
  fill(255);
  rect(140, 100, 575, 390);

}

void draw()
{
  smooth();
  if (keyPressed)
  {
    if (key == 'c' || key == 'C')
    {
      background (255);
      fill(255);
      rect(140, 100, 575, 390);
    }
  }
  draw_buttons();
  draw_colors();
  draw_paint();
}

void draw_buttons()
{
  draw_buttons_point();
  draw_buttons_line();
  draw_buttons_circle();
  draw_buttons_rect();
  draw_buttons_eraser();
}

void draw_buttons_point()
{
  //point button
  if (pointButton) fill(0);
  else fill(50);

  rect(140, 520, 90, 60);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(185, 550, 10, 10);
}

void draw_buttons_line()
{
  //line button
  if (lineButton) fill(0);
  else fill(50);

  rect(260, 520, 90, 60);
  stroke(255, 255, 255);
  strokeWeight(10);
  line(290, 565, 320, 535);
  //reset
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(0);
}

void draw_buttons_circle()
{
  //circle button
  if (circleButton) fill(0);
  else fill(50);

  rect(380, 520, 90, 60);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(425, 550, 30, 30);
}

void draw_buttons_rect()
{
  //rect button
  if (rectButton) fill(0);
  else fill(50);

  rect(500, 520, 90, 60);
  fill(255);
  rect(530, 540, 30, 20);
}

void draw_buttons_eraser()
{
  //eraser button
  if (eraserButton) fill(0);
  else fill(50);

  rect(625, 520, 90, 60);
  fill(255);
  rect(650, 540, 7, 20);
  rect(660, 540, 30, 20);
}

void draw_colors()
{
  stroke(0);
  fill(#FFFFFF);//white
  rect(730, 100, 40, 20);

  fill(#C0C0C0);//silver
  rect(730, 120, 40, 20);

  fill(#808080);//gray
  rect(730, 140, 40, 20);

  fill(#000000);//black
  rect(730, 160, 40, 20);

  fill(#FF0000);//red
  rect(730, 180, 40, 20);

  fill(#800000);//maroon
  rect(730, 200, 40, 20);

  fill(#FFFF00);//yellow
  rect(730, 220, 40, 20);

  fill(#808000);//olive
  rect(730, 240, 40, 20);

  fill(#00FF00);//lime
  rect(730, 260, 40, 20);

  fill(#008000);//green
  rect(730, 280, 40, 20);

  fill(#00FFFF);//aqua
  rect(730, 300, 40, 20);

  fill(#008080);//teal
  rect(730, 320, 40, 20);

  fill(#0000FF);//blue
  rect(730, 340, 40, 20);

  fill(#000080);//navy
  rect(730, 360, 40, 20);

  fill(#FF00FF);//fushia
  rect(730, 380, 40, 20);

  fill(#800080);//purple
  rect(730, 400, 40, 20);

  fill(current);//current
  rect(730, 450, 40, 40);
}

void draw_paint()
{
  if (mouseX > 140 && mouseX < 715 && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 490 && mousePressed)
  {
    noStroke();
    if (lineButton)
    {
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
    }

    if (eraserButton)
    {
      fill(color(#FFFFFF));
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed()
{
  //point button
  if (mouseX > 140 && mouseX < 230 && mouseY > 520 && mouseY < 580)
  {
    pointButton=true;
    lineButton=false;
    circleButton=false;
    rectButton=false;
    eraserButton=false;
  }

  //line button
  if (mouseX > 260 && mouseX < 350 && mouseY > 520 && mouseY < 580)
  {
    pointButton=false;
    lineButton=true;
    circleButton=false;
    rectButton=false;
    eraserButton=false;
  }

  //circle button
  if (mouseX > 380 && mouseX < 470 && mouseY > 520 && mouseY < 580)
  {
    pointButton=false;
    lineButton=false;
    circleButton=true;
    rectButton=false;
    eraserButton=false;
  }

  //rect button
  if (mouseX > 500 && mouseX < 590 && mouseY > 520 && mouseY < 580)
  {
    pointButton=false;
    lineButton=false;
    circleButton=false;
    rectButton=true;
    eraserButton=false;
  }

  //rect button
  if (mouseX > 625 && mouseX < 715 && mouseY > 520 && mouseY < 580)
  {
    pointButton=false;
    lineButton=false;
    circleButton=false;
    rectButton=false;
    eraserButton=true;
  }

  //-----------------------------COLORS--------------------------------

  //white
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 120)
  {
    current=color(#FFFFFF);
  }

  //silver
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 120 && mouseY < 140)
  {
    current=color(#C0C0C0);
  } 

  //gray
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 140 && mouseY < 160)
  {
    current=color(#808080);
  }   

  //black
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 160 && mouseY < 180)
  {
    current=color(#000000);
  }   

  //red
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 180 && mouseY < 200)
  {
    current=color(#FF0000);
  }   

  //maroon
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 200 && mouseY < 220)
  {
    current=color(#800000);
  }   

  //yellow
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 220 && mouseY < 240)
  {
    current=color(#FFFF00);
  }   

  //olive
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 240 && mouseY < 260)
  {
    current=color(#808000);
  }   

  //lime
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 260 && mouseY < 280)
  {
    current=color(#00FF00);
  }

  //green
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 280 && mouseY < 300)
  {
    current=color(#008000);
  }

  //aqua
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 300 && mouseY < 320)
  {
    current=color(#00FFFF);
  }

  //teal
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 320 && mouseY < 340)
  {
    current=color(#008080);
  }  

  //blue
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 340 && mouseY < 360)
  {
    current=color(#0000FF);
  }  

  //navy
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 360 && mouseY < 380)
  {
    current=color(#000080);
  }  

  //fushia
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 380 && mouseY < 400)
  {
    current=color(#FF00FF);
  }  

  //purple
  if (mouseX > 730 && mouseX < 770 && mouseY > 400 && mouseY < 420)
  {
    current=color(#800080);
  }  

  //-----------------------------DRAW----------------------------

  //define palet
  if (mouseX > 140 && mouseX < 715 && mouseY > 100 && mouseY < 490)
  {
    noStroke();
    if (pointButton)
    {
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
    }

    if (circleButton)
    {
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
    }

    if (rectButton)
    {
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
      rectMode(CORNER);
    }
  }
}
```

I need to control the brightness, hue, and saturation as well as the size of the shapes created with sliders, and I can't figure it out without breaking my code!

Comment: this isn't javascript

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions, and it isn't really designed for you to post your entire sketch here. Instead, try to narrow your question down to a specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question, and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire project.

That being said, I can try to help in a general sense: you need to break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Get the sliders showing. Start over with a blank sketch, and implement a slider that just changes the background color. You can either code the slider yourself, or use a GUI library listed on [the Processing libraries page](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/). Get that working perfectly before moving on.

**Step 2:** Write code that takes arguments for the brightness, hue, saturation, etc. Get this working completely separately from the slider sketch. Get this working first with hardcoded values, then get it working with variables, then with a function that takes arguments, etc. The exact path isn't the point. The point is to work forward in small steps.

**Step 3:** When you have both of those working perfectly by themselves, then you'll be able to combine them into a single sketch. Again, start small. Start with a blank sketch, and add a tiny piece of code at a time. Build your way towards your end goal instead of looking at it and saying you don't know how to get it working.

Then if you get stuck, post a more specific question and an MCVE, and we'll go from there. Good luck.